# Jackson2 marshalling wrapper class with generics

Tags: java, jackson

I have a wrapper json object for example

```
{
  "id": 23,
  "name": "teset",
  "type": "person",
  "_data": {
    "address": 23432
  }
}
```

my java object would look like this

```
public class Wrapper<D>{
    private Integer id;
    private String type;
    @JsonProperty("_data")
    private D  data;
...
}
```

i cannot find a way to have the object mapper do this

`Wrapper<Person> wrapped = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStream,Wrapper.class);`

is this not supported, i haven't been able to find much information about generics in Jackson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

- The main issue is that you are not specifying the desired parametrized type of `Wrapper` in your `readValue` invocation. You can fix this by using (simplified form): `Wrapper<Person> wrapped = om.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Wrapper<Person>>() {});`
- Also, your JSON features a `name` property that is not apparently present in your `Wrapper` class. You either have it and haven't posted it, or you can configure your `ObjectMapper` to ignore unknown properties: `objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);`

Here's an example:

```
public static class Wrapper<D> {
    // making fields public for simplicity, 
    // use public getters and private fields of course
    public Integer id;
    public String type;
    @JsonProperty("_data")
    public D  data;
}
public static class Person {
    // adding address field as a public int, 
    // same as above, encapsulate properly in real life
    public int address;
}
```

Then, in a main method somewhere...

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

// your example JSON
String json = "{\"id\":23,\"name\":\"test\",\"type\":\"person\",\"_data\":"
+ "{\"address\":23432}}";
Wrapper<Person> wrapped = om.readValue(
    json, new TypeReference<Wrapper<Person>>() {}
);

// printing class/hashCode of the resolved generic type
System.out.println(wrapped.data);
// casting as Person and printing actual property
System.out.println(((Person)wrapped.data).address);
```

**Output** (similar to...)

```
test.Main$Person@dfd3711
23432
```

**Explanation** for `TypeReference`, from the [docs](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html):

> This generic abstract class is used for obtaining full generics type
>   information by sub-classing; it must be converted to ResolvedType
>   implementation (implemented by JavaType from "databind" bundle) to be
>   used. Class is based on ideas from
>   http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html, Additional
>   idea (from a suggestion made in comments of the article) is to require
>   bogus implementation of Comparable (any such generic interface would
>   do, as long as it forces a method with generic type to be
>   implemented). to ensure that a Type argument is indeed given.
>
> Usage is by sub-classing: here is one way to instantiate reference to
>   generic type List:
>
> `TypeReference ref = new TypeReference<List<Integer>>() { };`
>
> which can be passed to methods that accept TypeReference, or resolved
>   using TypeFactory to obtain ResolvedType.

Comment: thanks alot for the quick and thorough answer, really helped me out!